# Date is not saving to database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating an appointment plugin, in that for already members and new members are there. in already member area the date entry is not entring into db. but when displaying the variale contains the date. i'm have been checking this from morning but didn't get what is the error. my code is:

```
 $source = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['apdatetime']));
$datetime = explode(',', $source);
$dates = $datetime[0];
  $app_time = $datetime[1];
if($app_time < 12){
   $app_session = 'am';
  }
 else{
    $app_session ='pm';
   }
$splitdatet = explode('/', $dates);
$yyear = $splitdatet[2];
$mmonth = $splitdatet[1];

$ddate = $splitdatet[0];
$app_date = $yyear . "-" . $mmonth . "-" . $ddate;


if ($_POST['isnewpatient'] == "false") {


        //$cSql = "select * from " . WP_contact . " where appointments_c_patientid='" . trim($_POST['ptntid']) . "' ";
        $cSql = "select * from " . WP_eemail_TABLE_SUB . " where eemail_patient_id='" . trim($_POST['ptntid']) . "' ";

        $data = $wpdb->get_results($cSql);
        if (empty($data )) {
            $err = 1;
            echo "<div id='message' class='aerror'>No such patient ID exists....</div>";
        } else {

            @$mobile = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($data[0]->eemail_mobile_sub));
            @$email = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($data[0]->eemail_email_sub));
            @$name = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($data[0]->eemail_name_sub));
           $sqlss = "insert into " . WP_Appointments .
                    " (`appointments_patient_id`,`appointments_date`,`appointments_time`,`appointments_session`,`appointments_reg_date`) VALUES ('" .
                    mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['ptntid'])) . "','" .
                    $app_date . "','" .
                    $app_time . "','" .
                    $app_session . "',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() )";
      $dd=$wpdb->get_results($sqlss);
var_dump($dd);
echo 'Date:'.$app_date;
            // return $suc;
            echo "<div id='message' class='asuccess' >Request has been sent for appointment</div>";
        }
    }
```

The output of the var_dump is `array[0]`  and $app_date is `Date:2014-10-22`
The db entry is

```
appointments_id           :393
appointments_patient_id   : 9999999999
appointments_date         : 0000-00-00
appointments_time         : 9:00
appointments_session      : am
appointments_reg_date     : 2014-09-25 14:21:35
```

could anyone please point out the mistake in the code if any??

Comment: As a side note, please do not use `Mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated. You should be using `PDO` or `MySQLi`

Comment: Mysql follows yyyy-mm-dd format so convert your date in mysql date format before storning it in database.

Comment: Ok thank you... i will take care of that.. but can u plz help me to findout the error which causes the date field to not saving.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola: i have already converted it frnd. the converted date in format is stored in the variable $app_date and its output display is " 2014-10-22"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert your string into date object like this:

```
$app_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($app_date));
```

Comment: Ok i tried that and it worked but a small correction i used "$app_date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dates));".. anyways thank u :)

Comment: can i ask u a doubt? do u know what may be the reason behind the form submission saves same entry two times in database.?